# Symfony 7 dynamic forms nested selects

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to follow the Symfony documentation for [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) but I've errors errors. I've just replace the 'Meetup' entity by 'Event' entity.

Event form (src/Form/EventType.php) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Event;
use App\Entity\Position;
use App\Entity\Sport;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class EventType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
  {
     $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Nom de l\'évènement'])
        ->add('sport', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Sport::class,
            'placeholder' => '--- Sélectionner un sport ---',
            'label' => 'Sport',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ])
    ;

    //
    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Sport $sport = null): void
    {
        $positions = null === $sport ? [] : $sport->getPositions();

        $form->add('position', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Position::class,
            'placeholder' => '--- Sélectionner un poste ---',
            'choices' => $positions,
        ]);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier): void
        {
            // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
            $data = $event->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getSport());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('sport')->addEventListener(
        /*  /!\ il y a 2 classes à importer :
        * 'FormEvents' AVEC un 's'
        * et 'FormEvent' sans 's'
        * "c'est génial !!!" (Patrick S.)
        */
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier): void
        {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $sport = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback function!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $sport);
        }
    );

    // by default, action does not appear in the <form> tag
    // you can set this value by passing the controller route
    $builder->setAction($options['action']);
} // -- buildForm()

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Event::class,
        // Ajout d'un atrribut HTML 'id' au formulaire pour le manipuler en JS
        'attr' => [ 'id' => 'form_event_new']
    ]);
}
}
```

Ajax request (templates/event/new.html.twig) :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}New Event{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Create new Event</h1>

{{ include('event/_form.html.twig') }}

<a href="{{ path('app_event_index') }}">back to list</a>

<script>
    {# S'assurer d'avoir les bons noms de route et de champs #}
    const form = document.getElementById('form_event_new');
    const form_select_sport = document.getElementById('event_sport');
    const form_select_position = document.getElementById('event_position');

    const updateForm = async (data, url, method) => {
        const req = await fetch(url, {
            method: method,
            body: data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'charset': 'utf-8'
            }
        });

        const text = await req.text();
        return text;
    };

    const parseTextToHtml = (text) =>
    {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const html = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');

        return html;
    };

    const changeOptions = async (e) =>
    {
        // target = 'event_sport'
        // getAttribute('name') =
        const requestBody = e.target.getAttribute('name') + '=' + e.target.value;
        console.log('-------------------------------------------');
        console.log('requestBody : '+requestBody);
        console.log('-------------------------------------------');

        const updateFormResponse = await updateForm(requestBody, form.getAttribute('action'), form.getAttribute('method'));
        const html = parseTextToHtml(updateFormResponse);

        const new_form_select_position = html.getElementById('event_position');
        console.log(new_form_select_position);
        form_select_position.innerHTML = new_form_select_position.innerHTML;
    };

    form_select_sport.addEventListener('change', (e) => changeOptions(e));
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Event controller method new() which define an action for the form:

```
#[Route('/event/new', name: 'app_event_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function new(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $event = new Event();

    /*
    * Il faut spécifier un 3ème argument à la méthode createForm() : un attribut 'action' avec comme valeur
    * la route où poster le formulaire (c'est bien la même qua sans l'attribut, c'est-à-dire cette méthode
    *  mais il faut la préciser pour que le script JS/Ajax puisse la récupérer
    * cf. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms
    */
    $form = $this->createForm(EventType::class, $event, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('app_event_new')]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $entityManager->persist($event);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_event_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->render('event/new.html.twig', [
        'event' => $event,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

Here the HTML code of the form (with (Bootstrap) :

```
 <form name="event" method="post" action="/event/new" id="form_event_new">
 <div id="event" id="form_event_new">
 <div class="mb-3 row">
 <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="event_name">Nom de l&#039;évènement</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" id="event_name" name="event[name]" required="required" class="form-control" />  
</div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 row">
<label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="event_sport">Sport</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select id="event_sport" name="event[sport]" required="required" class="form-select">
  <option value="" selected="selected">--- Sélectionner un sport ---</option>
  <option value="1">Football</option>
  <option value="2">Baseball</option>
  <option value="3">Rallye WRC</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 row">
<label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="event_position">Position</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select id="event_position" name="event[position]" required="required" class="form-select">
<option value="" selected="selected">--- Sélectionner un poste ---</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="event__token" name="event[_token]"  value="893083a7e1e0f0cabbf87843.t9skvnXm-GNKNpPmCrcSKh5kQhKr7wiENTyC0bme-40.4aoVjTi_zikORuatbNxCTSw2Nnn010G1ak_EncDXiNnxiHGHItW3N2d73g" /></div>
<button class="btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

My questions :

1 - I got the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: new_form_select_position is null
changeOptions [https://127.0.0.1:8000/event/new:66"](https://127.0.0.1:8000/event/new:66%22) when I submit my ajax request

2 - What is $sport->getAvailablePosition()? Should it be $sport->getPositions() ?

3 - Is there a simpliest method to do that? Maybe only Ajax without form events?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `new_form_select_position` is null which means that your `html` variable is probably null which means that `await updateForm` did not execute well ... can you console log `updateFormResponse ` and see if it contains what you would expect ?

Comment: `console.log(updateFormResponse) give `<!-- Object of class App\Entity\Position could not be converted to string (500 Internal Server Error) --> ...` , should I add a toString() method in the entity?